Should we have more off-topic Stack Exchange migration options?
Right now we only have a flag option for migrating questions to this meta.crypto.SE site. I find a lot of questions should be migrated to SO.SE or security.SE. Can we add some extra options for flagging?
Right now, if it seems to me to belong on SO.SE, I flag it as off-topic and as "asking for references" (ie. question is asking for a specific library or implementation recommendation). Is there a better flag to use?

Library recommendations aren't allowed on SO either.

If you want a question to be migrated, please just flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention" and say "this question should be migrated to X because Y".

This is probably a duplicate of my earlier question about migration paths.

The close list is usually fixed at 5 network wide. It is possible to have the list customised to each stack, but apart from this, that's pretty much all.
You can though flag this as off-topic Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong) and leave a comment on why it should be migrated to which site.
